How to get Pycharm terminal to run in Pycharm rather than pop up in a separate window? (Display question)
I know it's not preferable to take screenshots, but in this case I think it is necessary.
I am trying to get my Pycharm terminal to run inside Pycharm, rather than pop up in a separate window popping up every time I Run something.
Here is what it looks like when I run something:

It wasn't like this before and I looked online on how to change it back so that the terminal runs inside Pycharm rather than in a separate window.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Check the Window > Active Tool Window menu for options, as well as potentially closing that separate window and reopening it from View > Tool Windows.

I can't find any of those options in Settings, or am I looking in the wrong place?

Apologies, I've found it! :)
I tried to toggle with a few of the options, but still no luck. When I run anything it still pops up with a separate window

I got it, thank you. In the Run, if I click the wheel icon, then pin it to the Dock it does the trick. Thanks again!
